# SQL Query that inner joins on a certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Sql query which I use to create a view. But I need to refactor it, thus it will only perform inner join when *SALES.PKY* has a duplicate value or is not unique. How can I do it in a single query?

```
SELECT *
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN MAIN ON 
REPLACE(MAIN.KEY,'-','') = SALES.PKY 
AND REPLACE (MAIN.B,' ','') = SALES.SK
AND REPLACE (MAIN.P,' ','') = SALES.SP
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The explanation is not particularly clear.

Answer (score 0):

could you use a with statement to filter like this?

```
with dups as (
select *
from sales
group by dup_value
having dup_value>1
)
select
dups.*
,main.*
from dups
inner join main
on dups_key=main_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT *
FROM SALES INNER JOIN
     MAIN 
     ON REPLACE(MAIN.KEY,'-','') = SALES.PKY AND
        REPLACE(MAIN.B,' ','') = SALES.SK AND
        REPLACE(MAIN.P,' ','') = SALES.SP JOIN
     (SELECT s.PKY
      FROM SALES s
      GROUP BY s.PKY
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) ss
     ON ss.PKY = SALES.PKY;
```